# Seaborn does not show lineplot data in order

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Recently I've been practicing with Seaborn, and I've had the next problem:

I have a basic dataset:

[image]

I try to plot a lineplot as follows:

```
prueba = pd.read_csv('prueba.csv')
sns.lineplot(data=prueba, x="mes", y="cantidad")
```

Where **pd** and **sns** are alias for pandas and seaborn, respectively.

When I got the plot, I have the next:

[image]

Which is not what I need. I'd need the graph in order, like my original dataset. Something in the x axis like: **"marzo, abril, mayo, junio, julio"** and not "**mayo, marzo, junio, julio, abril** ".

I tried with the argument **sort=False** but it didn't work out.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,
Ciro.

Comment: SO is English-only. You can post in [es.so].

Comment: @Barmar can we get a reopen vote here, it was translated to English?

Comment: Yes!, reopen please. I didn't know I was posting in the English forum, haha.

Comment: Are you sure you are running the latest seaborn version (0.11)? When I try your example, the months stay in their initial order. `prueba = pd.DataFrame({'mes': ['marzo', 'abril', 'mayo', 'junio', 'julio'], 'cantidad': [10, 20, 50, 200, 500]})` [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MSgS.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for answering.

The problem was that I had an unupdated version of Seaborn. I could fix it by doing so:

```
conda update seaborn
```